# reactjs load images from their local path

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to load an array of images, through their path which i am taking from a rest api but i am taking the error:

Module not found: Can't resolve 'tempString' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\React\yiannis\touch\touch\touch\src\pages\en'

and the code is:

```
{photo.map(image=>( 
                              //tempString = image.replace("../","../../"),
                              this.setState({tempString : image.replace("../","../../")}),   
                               currentImage = require('tempString')
                              //Images.push(currentImage)  
                        ))}
```

Any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss const,you haven't define tempString but to pass date to it.

```
const tempString = image.replace("../","../../")
```

And here, what is 'tempString',I think there are some problems here.

```
require('tempString')
```

---

Edit 2:

```
const Image = []
{photo.map((image) => (
   Image.push(image.replace("../","../../"))
)}
```

Comment: is there any way to import or push the images into Images array without defining tempString as a const?

Comment: @yan I have changed my answer.Just omit the const.